# Running python in Sublime Text 2 getting error

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-construction, sublimetext2, sublimetext

so I have recently gotten into python and I use sublime text 2 alot for things like HTML and CSS and I want to use it for python too but when i try to compile with it I get the following error:

`[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Projects\\All Python Coding stuff\\Sublime Testing.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Projects\All Python Coding stuff]
[path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Panda Security\WaAgent\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin]
[Finished]`

I have changed the build system to python and I have restarted and even installed python again. When I run a python script in IDLE it works fine.

Edit 1.

So now i get the error:

`[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Weber\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Projects\\All Python Coding stuff\\Sublime Testing.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Weber\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Projects\All Python Coding stuff]
[path: /usr/local/bin]
[Finished]`

my `python.sublime-build' looks like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: Have you added the python executable directory to your system's path environment variable?

Comment: No I have not. Or at least I don't think I have.

Comment: How can I go about doing that?

Comment: For the record, you don't compile Python code as a separate step (unlike languages such as C++, Java, or C#). The runtime compiles it on the fly. You just run your program.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I knew it was something like that i just didn't know what else to call it.

Comment: @WebSpartan Given the error, it looks like you're just trying to run the program. You may want to edit the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the python directory to your system's path environment variabe.
To do that in windows you need go to Control Panel> System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings> in the advanced tab go to **Environment Variables**. In the environment variables in the **System Variables** area scroll down until you find **Path**. Select it and press **Edit**. Then a window should appear titled Edit System Variable where you have the variable name (should be path) and the variable value which is a long string. At the start of the string you need to manually add the python's directory. For example my python 2.7 directory is at **C:\Python27** So you need to add C:\Python27\ at the start of the string. So after you do that the value should now look something like that:

`C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files` etc..

Try that and tell us the results :)

Hope that helped

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: What if I have two python versions (32bit, 64bit) and want to make build systems for both?

Answer (score 1):

It happens for the reason that the cmd starts at "C:\Users\YOU". You have to "say" the complete path. I send the args "-u" and the my file's url directly to the python.exe.

Try it:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\Python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Obs: I'm using Python 2.7 and its executable file is in C:\Python27\ folder.