# My sublime text is not running the python programs

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am currently using sublime text build 3176 and I've also made a new build system for python 3.5, but while running the program, the console is giving me an error that it cannot find the file specified. It is showing the following error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.5', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\Samrat\\Documents\\lol.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\Samrat\Documents]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Samrat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Python 3.5 binary location to PATH variable and try again.

Also you may search the web before posting: [Running python in Sublime Text 2 getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467699/running-python-in-sublime-text-2-getting-error)